# Increase allocated memory for android studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Android studio on my laptop is dead slow even after being hosted in an environment of 8GB RAM. How do I enhance it? I have been going through different post in SO and tried what is being said in [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration).

Bottlenecks:

1. > Tried to edit studi64.exe.vmoptions : It throws an error saying I need admin access to edit or save anything in 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin' folder.
2. > Tried adding _JAVA_OPTIONS System variable in environment variables.
3. > Searched for vm options like files in UserProfile/.AndroidStudio1.5 folder. Found none

What else can I do ?
Also, how do I get to validate the allocated memory for Android Studio to work with? In one of the posts I saw that users were able to see memory used on the bottom bar. Mine looks as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Android Studio per se, or the Emulator?

Comment: Android Studio in particular

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for increasing the heap size for Android Studio is here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration for each platform.

You can display the heap measurement at the bottom by going to Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Show memory indicator.

Comment: I have been to that link as I mentioned in the question and it has no info concerned to my 1.5 version. Reg memory indicator I couldn't find the preferences option. Can you edit your answer to share the screen?

Comment: 1.5 has a folder for settings just like all the others listed. You'll be able to find it if you look in the same parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a helpful resource for future reference to memory and performance related issues with Android Studio:

[AndroidDeveloperResource](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)